# Map Data into another array using Hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, jsx

So I have a ton of data coming in through an Api that I do no need, and I want to isolate this data in another array.

I am trying to figure out how to do this using hooks.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 2976,
    "name": "Device 2",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 2977,
    "name": "Device 1",
  },
 Object {
    "id": 2978,
    "name": "Device 3",
  },
]
```

I have a Hook

```
const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
```

I want devices to end up with [Device1, Device2, Device3]

there is a bunch of other data in the array, but this is to give you a general idea that i ONLY need 1 piece of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array that's populated with just the names (or whatever you want)

```
objArray = [{
  "id": 2976,
  "name": "Device 2",
},{
  "id": 2977,
  "name": "Device 1",
},{
  "id": 2978,
  "name": "Device 3",
}];

// create a new array consisting of just the names from the objects
const arrayOfNames = objArray.map((obj) => obj.name);

setDevices(arrayOfNames);
```

You can think of Array.map as creating a new array from an input array, where each item is replaced based on the formula on the right hand side.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3];

numbers.map((x) => x)     // returns [1, 2, 3]
numbers.map((x) => x + 1) // returns [2, 3, 4]
numbers.map((x) => 0)     // returns [0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: ya, i can understand this, but is there a way i can set it to state in a hook?

Comment: `setDevices(arrayOfNames)` is doing that no? Or do you mean you want to put all this logic into a hook?